# GUI and Raycaster dont work together (three.js)

Tags: user-interface, three.js

I have the following code to add a gui and the ability to click on objects.
When I set the controls as `controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement);` the GUI works but the Raycaster doesnt seem to work.
If I define the constrols as `controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera);` the raycaster works, however once I click the gui on the corner, then wherever I move the mouse the values of the gui change, while if I close it, the GUI resize with response to mouse movements

Can Anyone give me any hint how to fix this?

At the moment works but I'm able to unclick from the control by simultaneously left and right clicking

This link shows how far I have gone and give you an idea of the problem
http://subsurface.gr/joomla/threejs/StreamFnc_ws.html

Here is the full code:

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            // global variables
            var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
            var container, stats;
            var raycaster, intersects;
            var threshold = 0.05;
            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

            var cube;

            // Parameters for GUI
            var params = {
                AAmin: 0.0,
                AAmax: 1000.0
            };


            // main functions
            init();
            animate();


            function init(){

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                //Setup Camera
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.name = 'camera';
                camera.position.z = 20;

                // Setup world
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );

                // Setup lights
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                scene.add( directionalLight );
                directionalLight.name = 'directionalLight';

                var directionalLight1 = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x002288 );
                directionalLight1.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
                directionalLight1.name = 'directionalLight1';
                scene.add( directionalLight1 );

                var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
                ambientLight.name = 'ambientLight';
                scene.add( ambientLight );

                raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
                raycaster.params.Points.threshold = threshold;

                // Main Scene
                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
                cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                cube.name = 'mycube';
                scene.add( cube );

                // GUI parameter
                var gui = new dat.GUI();
                gui.add( params, 'AAmin', -1000, 500 );
                gui.add( params, 'AAmax', 500, 2000 );
                gui.open();

                //renderer 
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //controls
                controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera);
                controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
                controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
                controls.noZoom = false;
                controls.noPan = false;
                controls.staticMoving = true;
                controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
                controls.keys = [ 65, 83, 68 ];
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render);

                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.dom );

                // events
                document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

                render();
            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
                controls.update();
            }
            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
                stats.update();
            }

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ){
                event.preventDefault();
                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;


                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
                intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( cube );
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ){
                    console.log("You click a cube!");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>If I understand correctly, the TrackballControls is stopping propagation of the mouseDown event (bound to the renderer.domElement) -- meaning your onDocumentMouseDown handler isn't being invoked. Try moving your document.addEventListener(...) to come before new THREE.TrackballControls(...).</s>

Responding to your comment below:

I see the problem now. There appears to be an incompatibility between TrackballControls and Dat.GUI in that the TrackballControls mouseup events stops propagation of the event, which causes Dat.GUI to bug out and get stuck resizing the UI for some reason.

I believe you can solve this by disabling TrackballControls when clicking the GUI, and re-enabling TrackballControls on mouseup:

```
gui.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(){ controls.enabled = false; }, false );
document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function(){ controls.enabled = true; }, false );
```

Comment: I moved the document.addEventListener(...)  as suggested but still doesn't work. I also updated the question and add a link with the page in order to see the problem